# How can I proportionately scale an SVG background image to always be the full-width of a footer div?

Tags: html, css, svg

I'm having a terrible time getting an image to scale the way I'd like it to in `HTML & CSS`. Hope it's possible to do this… I'm developing a site that is comprised of a `header, main content div and footer div`. All three of these divs fall within a master wrapper div. None of the divs are absolutely positioned or fixed to the browser window. In the footer div, I am trying to set a `SVG` vector image as the background as I will be also inserting text into this footer div. The `SVG` image is `800 x 240px` by default, but because SVG's are infinitely resizable, they will scale up. I would like this `SVG` image to stretch the width of the footer div proportionately. So, for example, when the browser is shrunk to `300px` wide, the image would be `90px` tall. If the browser is stretched to `1200px` wide, the image would need to scale to `360px` tall. The `SVG` should always be `100%` of the browser width and it's height should be proportionately sized.

I am wanting the `footer div` to be at the very bottom of the browser window so that there is no white space below the background image. However, I do not want to set the `footer div` as fixed to the bottom of the browser window. I am wanting the footer to come after the main-content div on page scroll. So, on longer webpage posts, the footer div will not be visible until the page is scrolled down a bit and will then scroll into view.

Thanks so much for any help! I can provide more information if needed. Still learning CSS & HTML! :)

Comment: For the footer to stay at the bottom of the page, search for "sticky footer", it's a common issue.

Answer (score 1):

```
<header>This is out header</header>
<main class="content">This is my content</main>
<footer>
    <div class="footer-inside">
    And here goes footer with background image
    </div>
</footer>
```

What I would do to put footer to bottom, use [flexbox](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Flexible_boxes) (it's 2015, everyone should support flexbox...),

```
body {
  display: flex;
  min-height: 100vh;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.content {
  flex: 1;
}
```

then make [padding hack](https://css-tricks.com/NetMag/FluidWidthVideo/Article-FluidWidthVideo.php) to make footer responsive.

```
footer {
    position: relative;
    height: 0;
    padding-top: 30%; /* 240 divided by 800 and multiplied by 100 */
    text-align: center;
}

.footer-inside {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    background: red url(http://ohdoylerules.com/content/images/css3.svg) no-repeat center center;
    background-size: contain;
}
```

Demo [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/vwnj7boq/)

Answer (score 0):

First set your SVG to scale proportionally:

```
<svg preserveAspectRatio="xMinYMin">
</svg>
```

Then set it as the background of your footer and state the background size with `cover`:

```
   .footer {
     background: #000 url(image.svg) top left no-repeat;
     background-size: cover;
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

In general to scale an SVG background image you need to set a viewbox, otherwise preserveAspectRatio will not work:

```
<svg
   viewBox = "0 0 90 70" 
   preserveAspectRatio="none"
   ...
```

Then in your CSS for example:

```
.logo{
    background:transparent url(images/matheboss-logo-w.svg) center center no-repeat;
    display:block;
    background-size:contain;
    height:50px;
    width:50px
}
```